# Why using directive behaves differently in global scope and in local scope?

Tags: c++, namespaces

When I write following code it gets compiled and executed properly:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace first
{
  int x = 5;
  int y = 10;
}

namespace second
{
  double x = 3.1416;
  double y = 2.7183;
}

int main () {
  using namespace first; //using derective
  using second::y;
  cout << x << endl;
  cout << y << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

But if I write using directives outside main function as follows,

```
using namespace first; //using derective
using second::y;
int main () {
  cout << x << endl;
  cout << y << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

It gives this compilation error:

```
g++     namespace03.cpp   -o namespace03
namespace03.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
namespace03.cpp:20:11: error: reference to ‘y’ is ambiguous
namespace03.cpp:13:10: error: candidates are: double second::y
namespace03.cpp:7:7: error:                 int first::y
make: *** [namespace03] Error 1
```

Can anybody explain why using directive behaves differently when it is used inside `main` and outside `main`?

Answer (score 12):

The using-declaration is just that, a declaration. The `using second::y;` inside of main is similar to declaring a variable `y` in that scope which hides any other `y`s in global namespace scope. When you use `using second::y;` in global scope, you have not hidden any names, since both `y`s are in the same scope.

Imagine your first example is like the following (please see the comments below for an explanation):

```
namespace first
{
  int x = 5;
  int y = 10;
}

int main () {
  using namespace first; // This makes first::y visible hereafter
  int y = 20; // This hides first::y (similar to using second::y)
  cout << x << endl;
  cout << y << endl; // Prints 20 
}
```

However, the second example is like:

```
namespace first
{
  int x = 5;
  int y = 10;
}
using namespace first; // This makes first::y visible in global scope
int y = 20; // This is global ::y
int main () {
  cout << x << endl;
  cout << y << endl; // Error! Do you mean ::y or first::y?
}
```

Comment: Thank You Jesse for quick reply... Please correct me if I am wrong... But when using directives are in main function still there is going to be 2 declarations of y. If so why compiler gives problem in second case only?

Comment: @user2235938: There are two declarations of `y`, but the using-declaration declares `second::y` inside of main, while `first::y` is declared in global namespace scope. Since `second::y` is declared inside of main, it hides `first::y`. Are you familiar with name hiding?

Comment: Sorry Jesse... But I am not able to understand. when both statements "using namespace first;
using second::y;" are inside main function it should declare both first::y and second::y in local scope and give compile error. But it doesn't and program compiles and runs successfully. And when both statements are out side main it does not even get compiled due to ambiguity. Kindly explain...

Comment: @user2235938: I tried to explain with an example. The important part here is that `using second::y` **hides** `first::y`. It is like declaring two variables with the same name in different scopes, the variable declared in the inner scope hides the variable from the outer scope.

Comment: @user2235938 see my answer it may answer your question.

Comment: @Jesse and Alex: Thank you very much for so good clarification and your kindness

Answer (score 7):

There is two major differences between using-declaration and using-directive.

**The First Difference:** (The obvious difference).

```
namespace first{
 
int x=1;
int y=2;
}
using first::x; //using declaration
```

This will allow you to use the variable `x` without *namespace-name* as an explicit qualifier, and note that this doesn't include `y`.

```
namespace first{
int x=1;
int y=2;
}
using namespace first;// using directive
```

This will allow you to use all variable inside the namespace `first` without *namespace-name* as an explicit qualifier.

---

**The second Difference:** (Which is what you didn't understand).

I will explain to you why when you use both using-directive and using-declaration inside the main function you get no error, but when you try to use them both in the global namespace you get a compile-time error.

Lets say we have two namespace defined in the global namespace like this:

```
namespace first
{
  int x = 5;
  int y = 10;
}

namespace second
{
  double x = 3.1416;
  double y = 2.7183;
}
```

**Example 1:**

```
int main () {    
using namespace first;
using second::y;
  cout << x << endl; // this will output first::x;
  cout << y << endl; // this will output second::y;
  return 0;
}
```

The reason is that the using-declaration `using second::y` will make your variable `y` look like it's a local variable to the scope where the using-declaration is used, in this case it's used inside the main function. Whereas the using-directive `using namespace first` will make the variables that are defined inside this namespace `first` look like they are global variables and this is only valid inside the scope where the using-directive was used, in this case it's inside the main function.

so if you apply what is said above, you will know that if you did something like this:
**Example 2:**

```
 using namespace first;
 using second::y;

 int main () {    
  cout << x << endl; 
  cout << y << endl; // two definitions of y. first::y and second::y 
  return 0;
}
```

You will get an error, since both `first::y` and `second::y` will behave as if they were defined in the global namespace, so you will end up with breaking the One Definition Rule.